# A continuous map that is not a proper map

Tags: general-topology

I know that if a map is proper then it is continuous. But to disprove the converse I am trying to think of a counter example of a continuous map that is not proper.

Comment: What is a "proper" map?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map

Comment: If  preimages of compact sets are compact sets

Comment: A map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is proper if and only if, for any compact subspace $K \subseteq Y$ the inverse image $f^{-1}(K) \subseteq X$ is compact.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example that is not using the discrete topology. The inclusion map
$$
i: (-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}
$$
is continuous but not proper, as $i^{-1}\left([-1,1] \right) = (-1,1)$ is not compact.

This example shows that even an embedding may not be proper.

Comment: I know intuitively that $i$ is continuous but a map is continuous iff inverse images of closed sets are closed. But here we have that the inverse image of a closed set is open. Surely this shows that $i$ cannot be continuous. I know that I am missing something.

Comment: It is continuous. You are misunderstanding the concept of subset topology. $(-1,1)$ is obviously closed in $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Also, the fact that a subset is open does not contradict the fact that it is closed. For example, $\mathbb{R}$ is open and closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Let $\Bbb Z$ have the discrete topology, and let

$$f:\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z:\langle n,m\rangle\mapsto n$$

be the projection to the first factor. Clearly $f$ is continuous, since its domain has the discrete topology, but $f^{-1}[\{n\}]=\{n\}\times\Bbb Z$ is not compact for any $n\in\Bbb Z$, so $f$ is not proper.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be any noncompact space. Then $X\rightarrow\ast$ is not proper.